# Ada: How to Iterate over a private map?

Tags: containers, ada

Consider the following:

```
with Ada.Containers.Hashed_Maps;
with Ada.Containers; use Ada.Containers;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Main is
   
   package Tiles is
      -- Implementation is completely hidden
      type Tile_Type is private;
      type Tile_Set is tagged private;
      type Tile_Key is private;
      
      procedure Add (Collection : in out Tile_Set; Tile : Tile_Type);
      function Get (Collection : in Tile_Set; Key : Natural) return Tile_Type;
      function Make (Key : Natural; Data : Integer) return Tile_Type;
      function Image (Tile : Tile_Type) return String;

   private
      
      type Tile_Key is record
         X : Natural;
      end record;
      
      function Tile_Hash (K : Tile_Key) return Hash_Type is
        (Hash_Type (K.X));
      
      type Tile_Type is record
         Key    : Tile_Key;
         Data   : Integer;
      end record;
    
      package Tile_Matrix is new Ada.Containers.Hashed_Maps
        (Element_Type        => Tile_Type,
         Key_Type            => Tile_Key,
         Hash                => Tile_Hash,
         Equivalent_Keys     => "=");

      use Tile_Matrix;

      type Tile_Set is new Tile_Matrix.Map with null record;

   end Tiles;
   
   package body Tiles is
      
      procedure Add (Collection : in out Tile_Set; Tile : Tile_Type) is
      begin
         Collection.Include (Key => Tile.Key, New_Item => Tile);
      end Add;
      
      function Get (Collection : in Tile_Set; Key : Natural) return Tile_Type is
         K       : Tile_Key := (X => Key);
         C       : Cursor := Collection.Find (Key => K);
      begin -- For illustration, would need to handle missing keys
         return Result : Tile_Type do
            Result := Collection (C);
         end return;
      end Get;
      
      function Image (Tile : Tile_Type) return String is
        (Tile.Key.X'Image & '=' & Tile.Data'Image);
      
      function Make (Key : Natural; Data : Integer) return Tile_Type is
         New_Key : Tile_Key := (X => Key);
      begin
         return Result : Tile_Type do
            Result.Key := New_Key;
            Result.Data := Data;
         end return;
      end Make;
   end Tiles;
   
   use Tiles;

   S  : Tile_Set;
   T  : Tile_Type;
   
begin
   S.Add (Make (Key => 1, Data => 10));
   T := S.Get (1);
   Put_Line (Image (T)); -- 1, 10
   
   S.Add (Make (Key => 2, Data => 20));
   T := S.Get (2);
   Put_Line (Image (T)); -- 1, 20
   
   for X in S loop -- Fails: cannot iterate over "Tile_Set"
                   --     +: to iterate directly over the elements of a container, write "of S"
                   -- but "for X of S" doesn't work either.
      T := S (X);  -- Fails: array type required in indexed component
                   -- presumably because X isn't a cursor?
      Put_Line (Image (T));
   end loop;
end;
```

It seems to me that the compiler has enough knowledge to iterate over a Tile_Set and I'm supposing it won't because I haven't exposed an iterator.

How should I modify this so that 'for X is S loop' is valid?

More generally, what is the idiom for hiding the implementation of underlying containers, whilst exposing indexing, iterating etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It seems to me that the compiler has enough knowledge to iterate over a Tile_Set and I'm supposing it won't because I haven't exposed an iterator.

That assessment is correct. To be able to loop over a type, the type needs to define the aspects `Default_Iterator` and `Iterator_Element`, as described in [LRM 5.5.1](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-5-5-1.html), and the aspect `Constant_Indexing` as described in [LRM 4.1.6](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-1-6.html). Both sections read

> These aspects are inherited by descendants of type T (including T'Class).

This means that since `Tile_Set` inherits from `Tile_Matrix.Map`, it does inherit these aspects which are defined on that map. However, since the inheritance relation is private, the aspects are not visible outside of that package.

You also cannot set them for the private type explicitly since 4.1.6 says

> The aspects shall not be overridden, but the functions they denote may be.

Setting them on the private type would override the aspects inherited in the private part.

That leaves you with two options:

- Make the inheritance relation public so that you get immediate access to all of the aspects.
- Make `Tile_Set` encapsulate the `Hashed_Map` value, so that you can implement your own iteration on the type.

The second option would look like this:

```vhdl
   type Cursor is private;

   type Tile_Set is private
     with Default_Iterator => Iterate,
          Iterator_Element => Tile_Type,
          Constant_Indexing => Constant_Reference;

   function Has_Element (Position: Cursor) return Boolean;

   package Tile_Set_Iterator_Interfaces is new
     Ada.Iterator_Interfaces (Cursor, Has_Element);

   type Constant_Reference_Type
     (Element : not null access constant Tile_Type) is private
      with Implicit_Dereference => Element;

   function Iterate (Container: in Tile_Set) return 
     Tile_Set_Iterator_Interfaces.Forward_Iterator'Class;

   function Constant_Reference (Container : aliased in Tile_Set;
                                Position  : Cursor)
     return Constant_Reference_Type;
private
   
   -- ..
   
   type Cursor is record
      Data : Tile_Matrix.Cursor;
   end record;

   type Tile_Set is record
      Data : Tile_Matrix.Map;
   end record;
```

In the implementation of these subroutines, you can simply delegate to the `Tile_Matrix` subroutines.

The lesson is that you shouldn't inherit when your actual intent is composition.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, but there's the rub: in order to be able to write "package Tile_Matrix is new Ada.Containers.Hashed_Maps...", I have to make the full definitions of Tile_Key and Tile_Type public too, which defeats the object of the exercise. How would I implement the iterator interfaces that you suggest?

Comment: @smirkingman I edited the answer providing guidance for doing that. I forgot about `Constant_Indexing` which renders my original solution unviable as you can't re-define it on a type that already has it.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I've tried, but haven't yet the skills to flesh the bodies out myself. Could I possibly ask you to provide a complete sample that compiles please?

Comment: @smirkingman That is out of scope for StackOverflow since it also requires changes to your code, but since I don't have anything else to do, [here](https://gist.github.com/flyx/70abba5548474ceabc838f288e34daa9) is a complete compiling code listing containing all necessary changes and additions.